# Akka actors: How to select some of them?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Given I have actor-system with multiple actors:

```
/users/actor1
/users/actor2
/users/actor3
/users/actor4
```

And, assuming I'm an `actor2`, and given every actor knows paths' of others, how do I:

1. Select `actor1`, `actor3`, `actor4` (e.g. everyone else but me) and send (e.g. tell or ask) message to them?
2. Select arbitrary actors, such as `actor1`, `actor4`, and do the same?

Documentation says that `ActorSelection` could be use to *broadcast* messages for possible *many* actors, but as far as I can see I can only select *one* actor per *one* `ActorSelection`.

So, do I need one instance of `ActorSelection` per needed actor, or can I somehow do magic and gather many needed actors in one `ActorSelection`?

Thanks :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html#Querying_the_Logical_Actor_Hierarchy), you can use wildcards (eg. "actor?" or "actor*") when creating the selection to choose multiple matching actors. But truly arbitrary sets seem impossible.